# VB.NET - Change system colors (Windows Colors) via application

Tags: vb.net, windows

Ok, so I have been trying to figure this out for a few days now, but I'm not sure if VB supports this functionality. I'm sure C includes some sort of support for what I'm attempting do do with : 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724940%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

But basically, I'm trying to alter the systems colors. For example, change the colors of the "Active Title Bar" or the "Desktop". I know there is a way using SystemParametersInfo to change the desktop image, but I'm pretty sure there's no method for altering the system colors. If anybody has any suggestions, I'm open to trying anything.

Comment: Why don't just P/Invoke the unmanaged C++ function that you linked?. Anyways I'm not sure whether that function will do what you mean, because system colors are stored on the .msstyle file of the current visual theme.

Comment: I thought about the P/Invoke but again like you said, i'm not sure either if the function will actually commit any changes to the color scheme itself. Most likely meaning another method will need to be used to attempt to aquire the result.